# Regexp for Pattern annotation in java

Tags: java, regex, annotations

How can I create a @pattern regexp for **pp-gfg76482_8498680983**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on what logic? You need to explain what pattern you're looking for.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should look like this :

```
\w{2}-\w{3}\d{5}_\d{10}
```

You can check the [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1sdh9v/1/)

**Explination**

```
pp-gfg76482_8498680983

\w{2}                       #Start with two characters
     -                      #Followed by a -
      \w{3}                 #Followed by 3 characters 
           \d{5}            #Followed by 5 digits
                _           #Followed by _
                 \d{10}     #Followed by 10 digits
```